# Why Vaadin take a lot of time to be loaded into a Spring Boot application and what is this generated front end?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin14

I was following this official **Vaadin** video tutorial in order to:

- Integrate Vaadin framework into my already existing Spring Boot project.
- Implement a push notification behavior in my project using Vaadin.

This is the video tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5sbGvW3S4I
And this is the GitHub repo of the example shown in the previous video: https://github.com/marcushellberg/fusion-push-notifications

**NOTE:** my already existing Spring Boot project contains several controller containing APIs that always worked fine until I integrated Vaadin into my project. After Vaadin integration it seems that I can still call the old Spring Boot implemented APIs but the startup of the project is now very slow.

**WHAT I HAVE DONE:**

1. First of all I addede **Vaadin** and related dependencies into my **pom.xml** file that now contains:

   ```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.easydefi</groupId>
        <artifactId>GET-USER-WS</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>GET-USER-WS</name>
        <description>Microservice that retrieves users from DB</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
            <vaadin.version>19.0.8</vaadin.version>
        </properties>

        <repositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->

            <!-- Main Maven repository -->
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>

            <repository>
                <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/</url>
            </repository>

            <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
            <repository>
                <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
                <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <pluginRepositories>
            <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>

            <pluginRepository>
                <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>

        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>



            <!-- Validation -->
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Security -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!-- JWT -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Lombok -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.22</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
                <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>nl.martijndwars</groupId>
                <artifactId>web-push</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
              <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
              <version>1.68</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.3</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- Vaadin and push request related dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
                <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.vaadin.artur</groupId>
                <artifactId>a-vaadin-helper</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>nl.martijndwars</groupId>
                <artifactId>web-push</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
                <version>1.68</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
              <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
              <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>



        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
   ```
2. Then I simply created the **MessageService** class shown into the previous video tutorial (this class contains the services that implement the business logic that send my push notifications):

   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
   import java.security.Security;
   import java.time.LocalTime;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
   import java.util.stream.Collectors;

   import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

   import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
   import org.jose4j.lang.JoseException;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
   import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

   import nl.martijndwars.webpush.Notification;
   import nl.martijndwars.webpush.PushService;
   import nl.martijndwars.webpush.Subscription;

   @Service
   public class MessageService {

   ```
    @Value("${vapid.public.key}")
    private String publicKey;
    @Value("${vapid.private.key}")
    private String privateKey;

    private PushService pushService;
    private List<Subscription> subscriptions = new ArrayList<>();

      @PostConstruct
      private void init() throws GeneralSecurityException {
          Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
          pushService = new PushService(publicKey, privateKey);
      }

      public String getPublicKey() {
          return publicKey;
      }

      public void subscribe(Subscription subscription) {
          System.out.println("Subscribed to " + subscription.endpoint);
          this.subscriptions.add(subscription);
      }

      public void unsubscribe(String endpoint) {
          System.out.println("Unsubscribed from " + endpoint);
          subscriptions = subscriptions.stream().filter(s -> !endpoint.equals(s.endpoint)).collect(Collectors.toList());
      }

      public void sendNotification(Subscription subscription, String messageJson) {
          try {
              pushService.send(new Notification(subscription, messageJson));
          } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException | JoseException | ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }

      @Scheduled(fixedRate = 15000)
      private void sendNotifications() {
          System.out.println("Sending notifications to all subscribers");

        var json = """
                {
                  "title": "Server says hello!",
                  "body": "It is now: %s"
                }
                """;

        subscriptions.forEach(subscription -> {
            sendNotification(subscription, String.format(json, LocalTime.now()));
        });
      }
   ```

   }
3. Finally, as shown in the video tutorial, I created this **MessageEndpoint** class that should be a controller implemented via **Vaadin** framework (it seems to me pretty different from the classic Spring Boot controller annotated using **@RestController**).

   import com.vaadin.flow.server.connect.Endpoint;
   import com.vaadin.flow.server.connect.auth.AnonymousAllowed;

   import nl.martijndwars.webpush.Subscription;

   @Endpoint
   @AnonymousAllowed
   public class MessageEndpoint {

   ```
      private MessageService messageService;

      public MessageEndpoint(MessageService messageService) {
          this.messageService = messageService;
      }

      public String getPublicKey() {
          return messageService.getPublicKey();
      }

      public void subscribe(Subscription subscription) {
          messageService.subscribe(subscription);
      }

      public void unsubscribe(String endpoint) {
          messageService.unsubscribe(endpoint);
      }
   ```

   }

Running my application into Eclipse\STS (as a Spring Boot application) in the console I obtain the following output:

```
21:13:30.110 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@5134951b

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v2.5.6)[0;39m

[2m2022-02-16 21:13:30.740[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.easydefi.users.GetUserWsApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting GetUserWsApplication using Java 16.0.1 on ubuntu with PID 14188 (/home/andrea/git/get-user-ws/target/classes started by andrea in /home/andrea/git/get-user-ws)
[2m2022-02-16 21:13:30.742[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.easydefi.users.GetUserWsApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[2m2022-02-16 21:13:30.853[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The Class-Path manifest attribute in /home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/license-checker/1.2.0/license-checker-1.2.0.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/license-checker/1.2.0/gwt-elemental-2.8.2.vaadin2.jar,file:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/license-checker/1.2.0/oshi-core-5.5.0.jar,file:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/license-checker/1.2.0/jna-5.7.0.jar,file:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/license-checker/1.2.0/jna-platform-5.7.0.jar,file:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/license-checker/1.2.0/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar



[2m2022-02-16 21:15:05.009[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[onPool-worker-3][0;39m [36mio.swagger.codegen.v3.AbstractGenerator [0;39m [2m:[0;39m writing file /home/andrea/git/get-user-ws/./frontend/generated/nl/martijndwars/webpush/Subscription.ts
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:05.018[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[onPool-worker-3][0;39m [36mio.swagger.codegen.v3.AbstractGenerator [0;39m [2m:[0;39m writing file /home/andrea/git/get-user-ws/./frontend/generated/nl/martijndwars/webpush/Subscription/KeysModel.ts
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:05.027[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[onPool-worker-3][0;39m [36mio.swagger.codegen.v3.AbstractGenerator [0;39m [2m:[0;39m writing file /home/andrea/git/get-user-ws/./frontend/generated/nl/martijndwars/webpush/Subscription/Keys.ts
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:05.035[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[onPool-worker-3][0;39m [36mc.v.f.s.c.g.VaadinConnectTsGenerator    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The class 'MessageEndpoint' doesn't have JavaDoc or it is invalid. This results in no TsDoc for the generated module 'MessageEndpoint'.
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:05.051[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[onPool-worker-3][0;39m [36mio.swagger.codegen.v3.AbstractGenerator [0;39m [2m:[0;39m writing file /home/andrea/git/get-user-ws/./frontend/generated/MessageEndpoint.ts
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:05.070[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:05.072[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[onPool-worker-3][0;39m [36mc.v.f.s.c.g.VaadinConnectClientGenerator[0;39m [2m:[0;39m writing file /home/andrea/git/get-user-ws/./frontend/generated/connect-client.default.ts
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:05.088[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[onPool-worker-3][0;39m [36mc.v.f.s.frontend.TaskUpdatePackages     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Skipping `pnpm install` because the frontend packages are already installed in the folder '/home/andrea/git/get-user-ws/node_modules' and the hash in the file '/home/andrea/git/get-user-ws/node_modules/.vaadin/vaadin.json' is the same as in 'package.json'
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:05.101[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.dialect.Dialect           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:05.103[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[onPool-worker-3][0;39m [36mc.v.f.s.frontend.TaskCopyFrontendFiles  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Copying frontend resources from jar files ...
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:05.163[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[onPool-worker-3][0;39m [36mc.v.f.s.frontend.TaskCopyFrontendFiles  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Visited 15 resources. Took 59 ms.
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:05.184[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[onPool-worker-3][0;39m [36mcom.vaadin.flow.server.DevModeHandler   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting webpack-dev-server
[38;5;35m
------------------ Starting Frontend compilation. ------------------
[0m[2m2022-02-16 21:15:05.774[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[onPool-worker-3][0;39m [36mcom.vaadin.flow.server.DevModeHandler   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Running webpack to compile frontend resources. This may take a moment, please stand by...
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:06.549[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator      [0;39m 
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:09.171[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36medFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Adding web access control expression [hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN')] for Ant [pattern='/api/users/email/**']
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:09.173[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36medFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Adding web access control expression [hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN','CLIENT')] for Ant [pattern='/api/admin/user/{id}/wallet']
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:09.174[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36medFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Adding web access control expression [hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN')] for Ant [pattern='/api/admin/**']
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:09.174[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36medFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Adding web access control expression [authenticated] for Ant [pattern='/api/users/test']
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:09.174[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36medFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for Ant [pattern='/auth', POST]
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:09.174[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36medFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Adding web access control expression [denyAll] for any request
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:09.189[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2aa50230, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@1d9cf9e6, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2f2a8313, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@258d85cd, com.easydefi.users.security.TokenVerificationFilter@4a274633, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@447ccb11, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5eb4e5e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@743a9410, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4a9a39f4, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5184289e, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@19c8054d]
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:09.724[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m LiveReload server is running on port 35729
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:10.085[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.m.MustacheAutoConfiguration     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Mustache configuration, or set spring.mustache.check-template-location=false)
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:10.593[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Installed AtmosphereHandler com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler mapped to context-path: /*
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:10.593[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Installed the following AtmosphereInterceptor mapped to AtmosphereHandler com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:10.642[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Atmosphere is using org.atmosphere.util.VoidAnnotationProcessor for processing annotation
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:10.652[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.atmosphere.util.ForkJoinPool        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Using ForkJoinPool  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool. Set the 
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:10.717[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m    org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:10.717[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m    org.atmosphere.interceptor.OnDisconnectInterceptor : Browser disconnection detection
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:10.718[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m    org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:10.718[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework  [0;39m [2m:

[2m2022-02-16 21:15:10.756[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Messaging ExecutorService Pool Size unavailable - Not instance of ThreadPoolExecutor
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:10.756[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Async I/O Thread Pool Size: 200
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:10.756[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Using BroadcasterFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcasterFactory
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:10.756[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Using AtmosphereResurceFactory: org
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:10.927[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8019 (http) with context path ''
[2m2022-02-16 21:15:12.065[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.easydefi.users.GetUserWsApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started GetUserWsApplication in 101.938 seconds (JVM running for 103.28)
<i> [FlowIdPlugin] Serving the 'stats.json' file dynamically.
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wdm｣[39m: Hash: 9f677f25a17f5c77cd19
Version: webpack 4.46.0
Time: 6415ms
Built at: 02/16/2022 9:15:14 PM
                                                         Asset       Size        Chunks                                Chunk Names
           VAADIN/build/vaadin-0-5485b8d50b007ceb85e3.cache.js   16.2 MiB             0  [emitted] [immutable]  [big]  
           VAADIN/build/vaadin-1-db8ba1789bab8338f498.cache.js    477 KiB             1  [emitted] [immutable]         
           VAADIN/build/vaadin-2-25cd85c3b420560f3de5.cache.js   21.7 KiB             2  [emitted] [immutable]         
           VAADIN/build/vaadin-3-c872be1197fca0bba181.cache.js    334 KiB             3  [emitted] [immutable]         
      VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-9833878af5f2893ad446.cache.js    726 KiB        bundle  [emitted] [immutable]         bundle
VAADIN/build/vaadin-devmodeGizmo-3f7568f9bfd933c1ef19.cache.js    469 KiB  devmodeGizmo  [emitted] [immutable]         devmodeGizmo
                                                    index.html   1.03 KiB                [emitted]                     
                                                 manifest.json  642 bytes                [emitted]                     
Entrypoint bundle = VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-9833878af5f2893ad446.cache.js
Entrypoint devmodeGizmo = VAADIN/build/vaadin-devmodeGizmo-3f7568f9bfd933c1ef19.cache.js
[../node_modules/.pnpm/@polymer/iron-icon@3.0.1/node_modules/@polymer/iron-icon/iron-icon.js] 5.5 KiB {0} [built]
[../node_modules/.pnpm/@polymer/iron-list@3.1.0/node_modules/@polymer/iron-list/iron-list.js] 59.3 KiB {0} [built]
[../node_modules/.pnpm/@vaadin/router@1.7.4/node_modules/@vaadin/router/dist/vaadin-router.js] 90.9 KiB {bundle} [built]
[../node_modules/.pnpm/@vaadin/vaadin-accordion@1.2.0/node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-accordion/theme/lumo/vaadin-accordion.js] 78 bytes {0} [built]
[../node_modules/.pnpm/lit-element@2.5.1/node_modules/lit-element/lib/css-tag.js] 3.03 KiB {bundle} {devmodeGizmo} [built]
[../node_modules/.pnpm/lit-element@2.5.1/node_modules/lit-element/lib/decorators.js] 13.6 KiB {bundle} {devmodeGizmo} [built]
[../node_modules/.pnpm/lit-element@2.5.1/node_modules/lit-element/lib/updating-element.js] 27.8 KiB {bundle} {devmodeGizmo} [built]
[../node_modules/.pnpm/lit-element@2.5.1/node_modules/lit-element/lit-element.js] 11.6 KiB {bundle} {devmodeGizmo} [built]
[../node_modules/.pnpm/lit-html@1.4.1/node_modules/lit-html/lib/shady-render.js] 13.6 KiB {bundle} {devmodeGizmo} [built]
[../node_modules/.pnpm/lit-html@1.4.1/node_modules/lit-html/lit-html.js] 2.56 KiB {bundle} {devmodeGizmo} [built]
[../target/flow-frontend/Flow.js] 15.7 KiB {bundle} [built]
[../target/flow-frontend/VaadinDevmodeGizmo.js] 36.6 KiB {devmodeGizmo} [built]
[../target/frontend/generated-flow-imports.js] 5.3 KiB {1} [built]
[../target/index.ts] 1.43 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./generated/vaadin.ts] 29 bytes {bundle} [built]
    + 579 hidden modules
Child HtmlWebpackCompiler:
     1 asset
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_0 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
    [../node_modules/.pnpm/html-webpack-plugin@4.5.1_webpack@4.46.0/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!../target/index.html] 1.15 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_0} [built]
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wdm｣[39m: Compiled successfully.
[38;5;35m
----------------- Frontend compiled successfully. -----------------

[0mNo [2m2022-02-16 21:15:15.573[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[onPool-worker-3][0;39m [36mcom.vaadin.flow.server.DevModeHandler   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started webpack-dev-server. Time: 10388ms
issues found.
```

My doubts are:

1. What is this mentioned Frontend that is compiled, this section of the output:

   ```
   ------------------ Starting Frontend compilation. ------------------
   [0m[2m2022-02-16 21:15:05.774[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[onPool-worker-3][0;39m [36mcom.vaadin.flow.server.DevModeHandler   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Running webpack to compile frontend resources. This may take a moment, please stand by...
   [2m2022-02-16 21:15:06.549[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
   [2m2022-02-16 21:15:06.560[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
   [2m2022-02-16 21:15:06.636[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m14188[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mJpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
   [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Project is running at http://localhost:40843/webpack-dev-server/
   [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: webpack output is served from /
   [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Content not from webpack is served from /home/andrea/git/get-user-ws/target/META-INF/VAADIN/webapp, src/main/webapp
   ```
2. Trying to access to the previous link (of this frontend: **http://localhost:40843/webpack-dev-server/**) I obtain a page containing something like:

   ```
   App ready
   Cannot GET /offline-stub.html
   ```
3. Is it possible to have a more light startup in some way? (maybe something can be removed), otherwise each time that I have to test my application I have to wait a lot of time in order to have my backend started and ready

Answer (score 3):

**Use a LTS release** of Vaadin (eg. Vaadin 14, or the upcomming 22) instead Vaadin 19.

**Verify your application.properties** and make use of (for example)

```
vaadin.blacklisted-packages=org/bouncycastle[,...]
```

to exclude these external dependencies from UI component/view scanning.

Define the whitelisted packages for (your own) UI component/view scanning needs.

```
vaadin.whitelisted-packages=<your/own/packages/with/ui/stuff>
```

Disable development mode and switch to production.
https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/tools/mpr/configuration/production-mode

**Think about your requirements** If you plan to implement push functionality only you may simply use [atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) itself instead of including a full blown fullstack frontend/backend framework like Vaadin which in turn pulls in a node.js server and certain other things you do not require.

Even the classic **Vaadin Framework** (v8) used GoogleWebToolkit where a simple Hello World took ~30s for a clean compile (due to the nature of writing code in Java and transpiling it into a (IMHO) oversized client side javascript.